# How to delete virtual interfaces

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-bridge

This is the part of the result of `ifconfig -a`.

```
ovs-system: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 72:8b:a7:2c:25:ef  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

s1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 06:5e:2c:fd:5d:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

These are virtual interfaces. I would like to delete them and I tried the below.

`sudo ip link delete s1`

But I got the below although I could delete other except the two by the command.

`RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported`

Could you help me?

Answer (score 3):

`ip addr` will show your virtual interfaces (highlighted pink):

[image]

`sudo ip link delete enp5s0` will remove virtual interface (link) `enp5s0`

Note in my case that's my ethernet and I don't want to delete it, but I had a whole bunch of other ones that were messing with my LAN games and getting rid of them solved a huge headache.

Answer (score 0):

I see the device "ovs-system", so I guess they were virtual devices of openvswitch(I will use ovs as abbr.). You have to use "ovs-vsctl" command to delete virtual devices of ovs. I'm not sure the device "s1" is a bridge or a port, and you do not seem to post all ports in system.

You can read man page of "ovs-vsctl" to see how to delete ovs bridge and ovs ports. Otherwise please post the result of "ovs-vsctl show", then I can give you the exact commands.

Of course, if you don't want to use openvswitch any more, you can just remove it, and reboot by:

```
$ sudo apt purge -y openvswitch-common openvswitch-switch
$ sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same problem, i had created a virtual interface named new1 (to get the name of device - ifconfig -a).
To delete the virtual interface, you should try iw, not ip.

Here is the command to delete

```
sudo iw dev <dev> del
```

In my case, it's

```
sudo iw dev new1 del
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with

```
ip link set s1 down
```

or with`ifconfig`

Also, you might want to check this out: [remove virtual interfaces](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-to-remove-virtual-interfaces-or-network-aliases/)

Comment: What is iplink? It is not found on my pc and I do know which package to download to get it. I checked the link before I wrote this here. I guess it is not for Ubuntu.

Comment: `ifconfig` no longer works in 18.04 as Netplan now powers the network (or Network Manager)

Comment: Mr. Robot http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ip-link.8.html

Comment: I tried `sudo ip link delete s1` already, which is on the link. What should I do for the next.